# How to get values of nodes attributes in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, getattribute

I'm trying to get values of `src` attribute of images that are in an array, but console shows "`item.getAttribute` is not a function" error.

**HTML**

```
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/f474c412850850.56033e5e60fd8.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2c/09/bd/2c09bdd34dac867792321898f6635e2c.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/e6/9a/a7e69a71125bb231adb1eceb50a60500.jpg" alt="">
```

**JS**

```
let image = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

const images = [];
images.push(image);

(function assignValidSource() {
    const sources = images.map((el) => el.getAttribute('src'));

    // do some other stuff with src later
})();
```

I can get `src` value only if checking it for only one element in this array:

```
const sources = images.map((el) => el[0].getAttribute('src'));
```

How can I get `src` values for all images in this array, so I can replace them later with `data-src` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.from` and pass it the HTMLCollection from `getElementsByClassName`, and use a mapping function (`Array.from`'s second argument) to get the `src`s from each element:

```js
const sources = Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName('image'),
  img => img.getAttribute('src')
);
console.log(sources);
```

```html
<img src="placeholder1.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/f474c412850850.56033e5e60fd8.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder2.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2c/09/bd/2c09bdd34dac867792321898f6635e2c.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder3.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/e6/9a/a7e69a71125bb231adb1eceb50a60500.jpg" alt="">
```

If you wanted to construct an array from a `getElementsByClassName`, either use `Array.from` (just like above, but without the mapping function), or spread it into an array:

```
const imageArray = [...document.getElementsByClassName('image')];
```

or use a plain `for` loop to push each element to an array:

```
const imageArray = [];
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  imageArray.push(collection[i]);
}
```

But often you can avoid such intermediate variables by using `Array.from` or calling an array function like `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
const sources = Array.prototype.map.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('image'),
  img => img.getAttribute('src')
);
console.log(sources);
```

```html
<img src="placeholder1.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/f474c412850850.56033e5e60fd8.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder2.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2c/09/bd/2c09bdd34dac867792321898f6635e2c.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder3.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/e6/9a/a7e69a71125bb231adb1eceb50a60500.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain me why it wasn't working in the first place?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, `images.push(image);` will only push a single value (that collection) to the array, which doesn't make much sense - you need to extract the individual values from the collection.

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes sense. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your console, map is not a function of images. You first need to convert your HTMLCollection into an array with Object#values.

```js
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

const res = Object.values(images).map(i=>i.src));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/f474c412850850.56033e5e60fd8.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2c/09/bd/2c09bdd34dac867792321898f6635e2c.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/e6/9a/a7e69a71125bb231adb1eceb50a60500.jpg" alt="">
```

To switch src and data-src around:

```js
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

Object.values(images).forEach(i=>i.src = i.getAttribute('data-src'));
```

```html
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/f474c412850850.56033e5e60fd8.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2c/09/bd/2c09bdd34dac867792321898f6635e2c.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/e6/9a/a7e69a71125bb231adb1eceb50a60500.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be converting the [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) returned by the method [getElementByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to an array. You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for this as shown on the next example:

```js
let image = document.getElementsByClassName('image');

(function assignValidSource() {
    const sources = [...image].map(el => el.getAttribute('src'));
    console.log(sources);

    // do some other stuff with src later
})();
```

```html
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/f474c412850850.56033e5e60fd8.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/2c/09/bd/2c09bdd34dac867792321898f6635e2c.jpg" alt="">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" class="image" data-src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/e6/9a/a7e69a71125bb231adb1eceb50a60500.jpg" alt="">
```